# Solr: Ignore casing of strings when calculating facet numbers

Tags: string, solr, case-insensitive, faceted-search

I have these values for the `title` field in my database:

```
"I Am A String"
"I am A string"
```

I want to make the title field available as facets in my search results.

Current result:

```
<lst name="title">
    <int name="I Am A String">4</int>
    <int name="I am A string">3</int>
</lst>
```

Desired result:

```
<lst name="title">
    <int name="I Am A String">7</int>
</lst>
```

I actually don't care which of the 2 available string options is chosen for the final result, as long as the same strings (case insenstive) are counted for the same facet.

I tried the following field definitions for the `title` field. I also added the resulting facet logic.

string = sees casing as different strings
string_exact = sees casing as different strings
text_ws = breaks up into words with casing intact
text = breaks into separate words
textTight = breaks into separate words
textTrue = breaks up in words with casing intact
string_exacttest = breaks up in words with casing intact

Here's my schema.xml

```
<field name="title" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>


<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" />

<fieldType name="string_exact" class="solr.TextField"
    sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>           
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>    

<fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<!-- A text field that uses WordDelimiterFilter to enable splitting and matching of words on case-change, alpha numeric boundaries, and non-alphanumeric chars, so that a query of "wifi" or "wi fi" could match a document containing "Wi-Fi".
    Synonyms and stopwords are customized by external files, and stemming is enabled. Duplicate tokens at the same position (which may result from Stemmed Synonyms or WordDelim parts) are removed.-->
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_dutch.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_dutch.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <!--<filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>-->
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>


<!-- Less flexible matching, but less false matches. Probably not ideal for product names,but may be good for SKUs.  Can insert dashes in the wrong place and still match. -->
<fieldType name="textTight" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" >
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_dutch.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Dutch" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <!--
      this filter can remove any duplicate tokens that appear at the same position - sometimes possible with WordDelimiterFilter in conjuncton with
      stemming.
    -->
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>


<fieldType name="textTrue" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" >
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_dutch.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Dutch" protected="protwords.txt"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

How can I make sure that the same strings (ignoring case) are grouped together when calculating the facets?

Answer (score 1):

The `string_exact` definition is almost what you need, but you need to have a LowercaseFilter applied as well, so that each sentence is lowercased. The KeywordTokenizer keeps the whole value as a single token (so you won't see it broken into separate terms based on whitespace), and while a string field doesn't allow any additional processing, a TextField with a KeywordTokenizer behaves the same way - but you can add filters to how the token is processed afterwards.

```
<fieldType name="string_facet" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>     
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>      
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. But I DON'T want it to be lowercased. I want to preserve casing. Please also see the post itself, as I know that the strings are cased differently, I want to pick any one of the differenly cased variants and use that. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: But you _actually_ say that you want that - you want the counts to be irregardless of casing, which means you'll have to index the tokens with the same casing. If you don't, they will be different tokens, and thus, count differently. I'd either normalize casing while indexing for the facet field based on a rule for the field (for example normal sentence capitalization (I am a ..), or I think you'll have to use your first version and iterate over the result and merge each entry manually (.. or fetch two facets and look up a capitalized version from the second facet. The first is more efficient)